# How do you bind Enter and Esc keys to OK and Cancel buttons respectively in a WPF dialog?

Tags: .net, wpf, key-bindings

My WPF app uses a dialog with Ok and Cancel buttons. I would like to bind the Enter key to the Ok button and the Esc key to the Cancel button. Seems like it should be a simple thing to do.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try setting the `IsDefault` property on the ok button to true, and the `IsCancel` property on the cancel button to true.