# Set default "ok" and "cancel" buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application written in C#. This application has dialog windows in it. Each of these dialogs have a "Save" and "Cancel" button. When a user presses "Enter" on the keyboard, I want to automatically "press" the "Save" button. When a user presses "Esc" on their keyboard, I want to simulated clicking the "Cancel" button. Is there a clean way to do this in WPF?

Thank you!

Comment: took a bit to find but: possible duplicate of [How do you bind Enter and Esc keys to OK and Cancel buttons respectively in a WPF dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031322/how-do-you-bind-enter-and-esc-keys-to-ok-and-cancel-buttons-respectively-in-a-wp)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are properties on the button for that: [`IsDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) & [`IsCancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.iscancel.aspx)

Set them to true on the respective buttons.